# How to send drawable name to server when converted to html?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have an EditText that contains a drawable image (any random image, I don't know which one). I'm trying to send it to server along with text by converting it to HTML.

On my server, I'm getting this:

```
<p dir="ltr">Hi, this is a text <img src="android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@a3fbc83"></p>
```

How do I send the name of the drawable file instead of this?

Comment: Do you want to transfer the file data too or only the name? Also do you have code for your current output.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the drawable file name by:

```
 String name = context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.xxx);
```